# AdsController script creates 50mb Garbage Collector

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I wanted to add Interstitial and Rewarded ads to the game I made. I added the RegisterEventHandlers() Function written in the Google Admob for Unity documentation to reload the ad when the ad is finished and called in Update. When you don't call it, garbage collector doesn't accumulate, but when you call it, GC starts to accumulate more and more?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool InitailzeOpened, OpenInterst, OpenReward, TeklifRandom;

    public GameObject AddOpening;

    public GameObject TeklifAdd;

    public float openTime, LoadTime, TeklifEt, TeklifGecerlilik;

    public Manager mng;

    BilesenScriptable SecilenPart;

    bool Show;
    void Start()
    {
        openTime = 1.5f;
        LoadTime = 150;
        TeklifEt = 60f;
        TeklifGecerlilik = 300f;
        StartCoroutine(SaniyeSayar());

        MobileAds.Initialize((InitializationStatus initStatus) =>
        {
            InitailzeOpened = true;
        });
        MobileAds.RaiseAdEventsOnUnityMainThread = true;

        mng = GetComponent<Manager>();
        Show = false;
        LoadRewardedAd();
        LoadInterstitialAd();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(LoadTime >= -1f)
            LoadTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(OpenInterst)
        {
            openTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(openTime <= 0f)
            {
                ShowAd();
                AddOpening.SetActive(false);
                OpenInterst = false;
                openTime = 1.5f;
            }
        }
        if(OpenReward)
        {
            openTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(openTime <= 0f)
            {
                ShowRewardedAd();
                AddOpening.SetActive(false);
                OpenReward = false;
                openTime = 1.5f;
            }
        }
        /*if(interstitialAd != null)
        {
            RegisterEventHandlers(interstitialAd);
        }
        else
        {
            LoadInterstitialAd();
        }
        if(rewardedAd != null)
        {
            RegisterEventHandlersRew(rewardedAd);
        }
        else
        {
            LoadRewardedAd();
        }*/
        RegisterEventHandlers(interstitialAd);
        RegisterEventHandlersRew(rewardedAd);
        if(TeklifEt <= 0)
        {
            if(TeklifRandom == false)
            {
                int sec = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,6);
                if(sec == 1)
                {
                    SecilenPart = mng.PcKasa[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, mng.PcKasa.Length)].GetComponent<PartController>().tip;

                }
                else if (sec == 2)
                {
                    SecilenPart = mng.Monitor[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, mng.Monitor.Length)].GetComponent<PartController>().tip;
                }
                else if (sec == 3)
                {
                    SecilenPart = mng.Klavye[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, mng.Klavye.Length)].GetComponent<PartController>().tip;
                }
                else if (sec == 4)
                {
                    SecilenPart = mng.Masa[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, mng.Masa.Length)].GetComponent<PartController>().tip;
                }
                else if (sec == 5)
                {
                    SecilenPart = mng.Sandalye[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, mng.Sandalye.Length)].GetComponent<PartController>().tip;
                }

                TeklifAdd.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = SecilenPart.Gorsel;
                TeklifAdd.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = SecilenPart.Price.ToString();
                TeklifRandom = true;

            }
            if(Show == true)
            {
                TeklifAdd.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                TeklifAdd.SetActive(false);
            }
            TeklifAdd.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = Mathf.Round(TeklifGecerlilik).ToString() + "s";
            if(TeklifGecerlilik <= 0)
            {
                TeklifRandom = false;
                TeklifEt = 60f;
                TeklifGecerlilik = 300f;
            }
            TeklifGecerlilik -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            TeklifAdd.SetActive(false);
            TeklifRandom = false;
            TeklifEt -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if(rewardedAd != null)
        {
            //RegisterEventHandlersRew(rewardedAd);
        }
    }

    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads. GEÇİŞ REKLAMI
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3962423406976447/8440621123";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
  private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
#else
  private string _adUnitId = "unused";
#endif

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the interstitial ad.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadInterstitialAd()
    {
        // Clean up the old ad before loading a new one.
        if (interstitialAd != null)
        {
            interstitialAd.Destroy();
            interstitialAd = null;
        }


        // create our request used to load the ad.
        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        // send the request to load the ad.
        InterstitialAd.Load(_adUnitId, adRequest,
            (InterstitialAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
            {
                // if error is not null, the load request failed.
                if (error != null || ad == null)
                {

                    return;
                }


                interstitialAd = ad;
            });
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            interstitialAd.Show();
            LoadTime = 150f;
            TeklifEt = 60f;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void RegisterEventHandlers(InterstitialAd ad)
    {
        interstitialAd.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {

            Time.timeScale = 0;

        };
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;

            if (interstitialAd != null)
            {
                interstitialAd.Destroy();
            }
        };
        interstitialAd.OnAdFullScreenContentFailed += (AdError error) =>
        {
            LoadInterstitialAd();
        };
    }


    private void RegisterEventHandlersRew(RewardedAd ad)
    {
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;

        };
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            if (rewardedAd != null)
            {
                rewardedAd.Destroy();
            }
        };
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentFailed += (AdError error) =>
        {
            Debug.LogError("Rewarded ad failed to open full screen content " +
                           "with error : " + error);

            // Reload the ad so that we can show another as soon as possible.
            LoadRewardedAd();
        };
    }










    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads. ÖDÜLLÜ
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    private string _adUnitIdRewarded = "ca-app-pub-3962423406976447/6231661698";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
  private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
#else
  private string _adUnitId = "unused";
#endif

    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the rewarded ad.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadRewardedAd()
    {
        // Clean up the old ad before loading a new one.
        if (rewardedAd != null)
        {
            rewardedAd.Destroy();
            rewardedAd = null;
        }

        // create our request used to load the ad.
        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        // send the request to load the ad.
        RewardedAd.Load(_adUnitIdRewarded, adRequest,
            (RewardedAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
            {
                // if error is not null, the load request failed.
                if (error != null || ad == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                rewardedAd = ad;
            });
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAd()
    {
        const string rewardMsg =
            "Rewarded ad rewarded the user. Type: {0}, amount: {1}.";

        if (rewardedAd != null && rewardedAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            rewardedAd.Show((Reward reward) =>
            {
                string isim = SecilenPart.NameName;

                int level = SecilenPart.Level;

                GameObject Kutu = Instantiate(mng.KargoKutu, new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(7f, 13f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.5f, 2f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-13.5f, -11.5f)), Quaternion.Euler(-90, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-170f, 220f), 0));
                Kutu.name = "cargobox" + isim + level;

                LoadTime = 150f;
                TeklifEt = 60f;
                TeklifGecerlilik = 300f;
                GameObject Bildirim = Instantiate(mng.BildirimAnimation, mng.Canvas1);
                Destroy(Bildirim, 1.5f);
            });
        }
    }


    public void InterstitialAdOpener()
    {
        if(LoadTime <= 0)
        {
            OpenInterst = true;

            AddOpening.SetActive(true);
            LoadTime = 150f;
        }
    }


    public void RewardOpener()
    {
        OpenReward = true;
        AddOpening.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ShowTeklif()
    {
        Show = true;
    }
    public void CloseTeklif()
    {
        Show = false;
    }

    IEnumerator SaniyeSayar()
    {
        if (LoadTime > 0)
            LoadTime -= 1f;
        if (TeklifEt > 0)
            TeklifEt -= 1f;
        if (TeklifEt < 0)
            TeklifGecerlilik -= 1f;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f);
    }
}
```

[ProfilerData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D77iy.png)

When I removed Register Event Handlers() the FPS in the game increased but when the first Interstitial was shown it was not showing again, the same goes for the rewarded ad.

Comment: Id add debugging messages as it sounds like its remaking your adintersialad object each time